# Stop recurring job during specific times

Tags: t-sql, sql-job, sql-agent

We have a job on our SQL database that runs periodically forever.
During predefined maintenance periods, we would like to have this job stop for a set time (say 12 hours) and then restart the regular periodic schedule.

We've tried using a separate job that disables it a the predefined time and a second one that enables it. This works but is not very neat.

Is there a better way to do this that only involves the job itself?

Answer (score 1):

Make a "maintenance schedule" table in some service database or MSDB (StartDate, EndDate, Description, etc.). Let the first step of your job check if current datetime within maintenance period. If so, just do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

If a session or transaction is associated with the maintenance process then you could use an *application lock* to have the regular job wait, or terminate, if it attempts to run while the maintenance is in process.

Using a locking mechanism allows finer control over the processes, e.g. the regular job can release and reacquire the lock between steps and wait (or terminate) if the maintenance process has started. Alternatively, the maintenance process could wait for the regular job to terminate (or reach a suitable checkpoint) before proceeding.

See [`sp_getapplock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for additional information.